# Xamarin Android Player Error when attempting to find VirtualBox

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, virtualbox, windows-10, xamarin-android-player

I have a clean install of Windows 10. After installing Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin Bussiness edition I installed **Xamarin Android Player** x64 and now I receive the following error:

```
Error when attempting to find VirtualBox please check it's installed and try again.
Xamarin Android Player will now exit.
```

A solution is referenced in [Xamarin fourms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47551/after-fresh-install-on-windows-10-it-says-unable-to-find-virtualbox) stating

> Fixed it by adding "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox" to my %PATH%

I am able to open VirtualBox version 4.3.28 r 100309 without issue.

How do I implment this solution or is there a newer solution?

Comment: For me I had to restart my PC. I installed version *5.04* and got the same error. But a restart fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing the Latest version of Virtual Box, Since v5.0 has fixes for Windows 10
http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.4/VirtualBox-5.0.4-102546-Win.exe

Changelog: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

```
Windows hosts: fixed crash when opening Windows dialogs from the VM process on Windows 10 (bug #14351).
Windows hosts: fixed host-only adapter creation issues on Windows 10 (bug #14040)
Windows hosts: fixed audio on Windows 10 (bug #14432).
Windows Additions: fixed a potential crash in the WDDM driver with Windows 10 (bug #14190).
VRDP: allow Windows 10 RDP clients (bug #14216).
Windows hosts: fix for Windows 10 build 10525 and later (bug #14502).
Windows hosts: fixed network adapter enumeration on Windows 10 (bug #14437).
VMM: fixed an issue with Windows 10 guest kernel debugging over the network for Hyper-V paravirtualized VMs.
```

I have a same problem too and installing the latest version has fix it

Answer (score 17):

I am running `Windows 10 Professional` and did a clean installation. Had the same problem. I opened the environment variables and the `"VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH"` was set to:

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
```

I changed it to

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
```

and it worked for me.. **(notice the last backslash)**

Thanks .. Ragnar Kofi Billy Force on facebook

Comment: I also changed the system environment variables and removed {\} and its work for me. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Add VirtualBox to your system environment PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers helped me. The Android Player installer was forcing the install of Virtual Box 5.0.4 which was not working on Windows 10 Home (build 14393.51).

What did work for me was to install the latest virtual box (version 5.1.2 r108956) after installing Android player. While I can't start the android devices from Virtual Box's manager, I have had no problems starting them from Android Player or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Just run as admin (Right hand click on desktop shortcut)