# Xamarin Android Player unable to find VirtualBox - How do I fix it?

Tags: android, xna, virtualbox, xamarin-android-player

I have created a Windows Phone 7 app using XNA 4.0 that I now want to port over to Android MonoGame. I am currently using a trial edition of Xamarin Business and I want to use an emulator to test the game as I do not currently have access to a physical Android phone. I have downloaded both Xamarin Android Player and Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.0.4 (I think that's the version I've installed, at least). When I open Xamarin Android Player, I'm just presented with the message:

```
Unable to find VirtualBox

Error when attempting to find VirtualBox please check it's installed and try again.

Xamarin Android Player will now exit.
```

No version of Visual Studio or VirtualBox is open and running when I'm opening Android Player. Does anyone know how to fix this issue so that I can the emulator running and test the MonoGame version of the app?

Comment: Have you tried with a different emulator as the docs here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/ state `The Xamarin Android Player is currently in preview. During the preview period it is only available to users with a valid Xamarin subscription.`

Comment: Are there any particular Android emulators you'd recommend?

Comment: Try the Intel HAXM from the Android SDK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Android Player Error when attempting to find VirtualBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673763/xamarin-android-player-error-when-attempting-to-find-virtualbox)

Answer (score 6):

After installing the latest preview release, v0.6.5.0 as of writing this, I ran into the same issue. It appears that Xamarin Android Player is expecting VirtualBox to be registered with the `%PATH%` environment variable, but it doesn't happen during the install process by default.

In this case, you just add `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` to PATH and you should be able to restart the Android Player just fine to begin downloading emulator images.

Here is a command-line approach to append this location to the existing PATH variable.

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
```

You can also do the same edit through the Environment Variables screen found under the System Properties screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just run as admin (Right hand click)